# How to send a boolean value

Tags: java, sockets, boolean

I am working on cows and bulls game which is to be implemented using networking concepts.both the server and client programs are written in java

my server program is
    import java.io.*;

```
import java.net.*;

import java.util.Random;

 import java .util.Scanner;

 import java.lang.*;



class Server3{

 public static void main(String args[])

throws Exception

{

 ServerSocket  ss=new ServerSocket(888);

 Socket  s=ss.accept();

 System.out.println("connection established");

 DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

   PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());

 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader kb=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String str="Welcome to COWS and BULLS Game";

 ps.println(str);

 String str1="Rules are :You need to guess a 3 digit number without duplicates";

 String str2="There are 2 variables namely Cows and Bulls";

String str3="Cows will give you the count of no of correct int in ur guess and bulls gives the   no of correct positions";
String str4="When the count in bulls is 3 you need to enter null";

String str5="now enter a 3 digit number";

 ps.println(str1);

ps.println(str2);

ps.println(str3);

 ps.println(str4);

 ps.println(str5);


Random gen=new Random();
int target=0;

while(hasDupes(target= (gen.nextInt(900) + 100)));

String targetStr = target +"";
boolean guessed = false;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int guesses = 0;

do{
    int bulls = 0;
    int cows = 0;
    String n;
    n=br.readLine();
    guesses++;
    String guessStr=n+"";

    for(int i= 0;i < 3;i++) {
        if(guessStr.charAt(i) == targetStr.charAt(i)) {
                    bulls++;
        }
    }

    for(int i= 0;i < 3;i++) {
            if(targetStr.contains (guessStr.charAt(i)+"")) {
                    cows++;
        }
    }

    if(bulls == 3) {
        guessed = true;
     dos.writeBoolean(guessed);
    }
    else
    {
     String Cows=cows+"";
     String Bulls=bulls+"";
     ps.println(Cows);
     ps.println(Bulls);
     dos.writeBoolean(guessed);
    }
} while(!guessed);
 String Guesses=guesses+"";

 ps.println(Guesses);

 }

 public static boolean hasDupes(int num){

    boolean[] digs = new boolean[10];
    while(num > 0){
        if(digs[num%10]) return true;
        digs[num%10] = true;
        num/= 10;
    }
    return false;
     }

 }
```

A part of my client program is:

```
 import java.io.*;

 import java.net.*;

class Client3

{

public static void main(String args[])

throws Exception

{

Socket s=new Socket("192.168.1.36",888);

 DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader kb=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String str,str1,str2,str3,str4,str5;

str=br.readLine();

str1=br.readLine();

 str2=br.readLine();

str3=br.readLine();

str4=br.readLine();

str5=br.readLine();

 System.out.println(str);

System.out.println(str1);

 System.out.println(str2);

 System.out.println(str3);

  System.out.println(str4);


 System.out.println(str5);

 String Cows,Bulls;

 String n;



boolean guessed=false;
do
  {
   n=kb.readLine();
   dos.writeBytes(n+"\n");
   Cows=br.readLine();
   Bulls=br.readLine();
   System.out.println(Cows+"cows and"+Bulls+"bulls");
   guessed=br.readBoolean();
  } while(!guessed);

  String Guesses;

  Guesses=br.readLine();

     System.out.println("you won after"+Guesses+"guesses");

   dos.close();

 br.close();

    kb.close();

    s.close();  


    }

     }
```

MY server needs to send a boolean value to my client and the client needs to read boolean value sent by server.I M not clear with the concept of how to send and read boolean values from client and server.

My client side error  is

---

```
 Client3.java:36: error: method readBoolean in class DataInputStream cannot be ap
  plied to given types;
 dis.readBoolean(guessed);
     ^
   required: no arguments
   found: boolean
   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
   1 error
```

i am not familiar with the methods of how to send and read boolean values.help me please

Comment: You are not showing us complete code. Various mistakes found in your code. Format your code and post it back. If you are using Eclipse IDE, press ctrl+shift+f. It formats your code.

Comment: @Eypros, can't say, that was a good edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Causes:**

> **1**. trying to use a variable without declaring it. <---
>
> **2**. misspelling a class or method name (remember, Java is case sensitive).
>
> **3**. the parameters used do not match a method's signature.
>
> **4**. the packaged class has not being referenced correctly using an import declaration.

Since I could not find anywhere in you declare variables br and output, so your error is because of **not declaring variables `br` and `output` in your code**

[Source and Read More](http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm)

Comment: br is an object to the bufferedreader class.I have just posted a part of my program.Actually i had created br object .would you please specify the signature for using "output"

Comment: what is output? what class is it?

Comment: @jyothirmaikaramsetty output is the type of `BufferedInputStream`

Comment: it is easy. BufferedInputStream output = new BufferedInputStream(InputStream in);